# Joining 2 tables together but only displaying 3 columns in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve the goal of ordering my 'Last Call Back' column in a table to give me the most recent date to the least recent in a list. This is in SQL if that helps , my select statement goes like

```
SELECT [Last Call Back] 
FROM dbo.Projects2 
ORDER BY [Last Call Back] DESC or ASC
```

but it's not displaying it from last entry.

Any idea on how i can achieve this in a query?

I would put a picture up of what it is i am trying to achieve but it won't let me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've searched SO but can't find something along these lines.

Comment: What type is the column `Last Call Back`? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: It's a Date type Time & i would but i require 15 Rep to upload an image.

Comment: I ment Tim not Time that would cause confusion.

Comment: Don't show images because the link will broke some time and we also cannot copy/paste them to sql-fiddle. Just post few lines of data and a header with the column-name(s). With `Date` you really mean `Date` and not `DateTime`?

Comment: The column type is 'Date' on the 'Last Call Back'

Comment: So you are missing a row?  Are you certain that it's really there?

Comment: i am having difficulties seeing two tables or three columns. your question is not making much sense to me

Comment: I have a column named [Last Call Back] in the table dbo.Projects2 , i am wanted to order the column so it displays the information with the last entry first & the first entry last? if that's a little clearer?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I got what you're asking but try this:

"SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY colum_name ASC"